# getUserMedia() in apache cordova? Any alternative?

Tags: ios, cordova, camera, getusermedia, crosswalk

I need some cordova plugin or function, which can stream video from device camera on ios. GetUserMedia **is not supported** on iOS.

I tryied Crosswalk project, it should support WebRTC (getUserMedia), but it doesnt work on phonegap build.

So I tryied cordova-camera-preview, but I am not able to make it fullscreen, because camera stream is shrinked.

Is there anybody, who used fullscreen video in cordova application?

```
<script>
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
                app_ready();
            }, false);

            function app_ready() {
                var vw = window.innerWidth;
                var vh = window.innerHeight;

                var tapEnabled = true; //enable tap take picture
                var dragEnabled = true; //enable preview box drag across the screen
                var toBack = true; //send preview box to the back of the webview
                var rect = {x: 0, y: 0, width: vw, height: vh};
                cordova.plugins.camerapreview.startCamera(rect, "front", tapEnabled, dragEnabled, toBack);
            }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

After deep searching I found out some augmented reality plugin called "ezAR videooverlay", check out npm -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/com.ezartech.ezar.videooverlay

Hope it helps someone